# Get status bar of automated page in webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium

im able to automate with webdriver with no problems at all (login, navigate, upload, etc)
but, im unable to get progress bar of the uploads, I notice there is a bar at the bottom of the page which has progress of uploads and navigations

[Status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL0O4.png)
[Status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mf3s.png)

how do I get the value of this bar!
ive tried

```
ChromeDriver cd = new ChromeDriver();
IWebElement we = cd.FindElementById("uploadForm");
we.Submit();
we.GetAttribute("state"); // or status and title
```

or is this something outside off webdriver scope ?

Comment: it's off from webdriver scope , if we talk about the picture you have shared..

Comment: thanks, I guessed that , now fortunately there is a progress in the page it self <div class="progress-percent">0%</div> but the progress in the page is not firing when I upload with we.SendKeys("C:\\Users\\msd\\Desktop\\newpic.zip"); here is the website https://www.action-manga.com/new-release/616-اختبار-مش-قصة-- I made a user and password for testing "msdyqb" could pls help me with this , thanks

Comment: Found it ! turns out I was clicking the upload button the wrong way ! it should be we = cd.FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'frmSBM button Ch_upLoader')]");
                we.Click(); instead of we = cd.FindElementById("uploadForm");
                we.Submit(); thanks !